# error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; found 'register'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, inline-assembly

I am facing compilation error while working with assembly instructions in VC++ as MACRO inline based assembler blocks.

```
error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; found 'register'
```

Here is the code:

```
_asm {\

        mov esi,dword ptr [pMemBlock]\
        sub esp,sizeOfblock\
        mov ebx,sizeOfblock\
        mov shrResult,ebx\
        shr shrResult,2\
        mov ecx,shrResult\
        mov shrResult,0\
        mov edi,esp\
        rep movs dword ptr es:[edi],dword ptr[esi]\
}
```

Regards
Usman

Comment: @Muhammad: Great. :) I'll add my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That blank line after the `_asm {` line will complete the macro. It should be deleted or have \ on it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
_asm {\
    __asm mov esi,dword ptr [pMemBlock]\
    __asm sub esp,sizeOfblock\
    ...
```

See [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/352sth8z.aspx).